# Data connector for Salesforce returns "{attributes={type=User, url=/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/User/005D00000086JriIAE}, Name=First Last}"

Tags: google-apps

I'm using the Data connector for Salesforce to populate Google Sheets with the result of an SOQL query. When there are multiple "." in a query column, I get

```
SELECT
id,
name,
Owner.Name,
Owner.Manager.Name
FROM opportunity
```

The final column renders as follows in Sheets.

```
{attributes={type=User, url=/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/User/005D00000086JriIAE}, Name=First Last}
```

In Developer Console, it renders as '[object Object]'.

How can I get the string value of the name?

Comment: The `[object object]` thing in the developer console is just an artifact of Javascript and/or how Salesforce wrote the display of query results (in the dev console).

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce Developer Console was never meant to be a permanent solution. It's fine for execute anonymous scripts, debugging, or running a quick query (most of the time), but this has been, and probably always will be, a limitation of the Developer Console. Consider using VS Code, Salesforce CLI, or even the Apex Data Loader if you want a better querying experience.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google's Salesforce Connector extension can't traverse 2 or more levels of relationship.  I tested using `SELECT Id, Parent.Parent.Name FROM Account` and got the same kind of JSON string as you did when there's a value at that level.